# Copiar una cadena a un puntero en C con strcpy()

Tags: c

Estoy estudiando C y vi que para copiar una cadena de caracteres a un puntero se debe utilizar la función strcpy(), ya que si se realiza una asignación directa, el puntero señalaría otra dirección de memoria.

Entonces escribí este código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
   char *mensaje = "Bienvenida";
   printf("Direccion: %d\n", mensaje);    //-->Direccion: 4210688

   strcpy(mensaje, "Despedida");
   printf("Direccion: %d\n", mensaje); 
}
```

Al ejecutar, solo sale en pantalla el primer printf(), luego hay una pausa y se termina el programa. No sé por qué falla. Agradecería si alguien me explicara.

Answer (score 4):

Tu idea base es correcta. Pero hay algunos detalles que explicar.

Primero, veamos lo que dice [la documentación sobre *cadenas literales*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal):

> String literals are not modifiable (and in fact may be placed in read-only memory such as .rodata). If a program attempts to modify the static array formed by a string literal, the behavior is undefined.

Que viene a ser, mas o menos:

> Los literales de cadena **no son modificables** (y de hecho pueden ser colocados en segmentos de memoria de sólo lectura tales como `.rodata`). Si un programa intenta modificar la zona de memoria ocupada por un literal de cadena, el comportamiento es indefinido.

Así tal cual, ya sería suficiente. No obstante, vamos a profundizar un poco mas.

Cuando un programa se compila y enlaza, el resultado final es algo capaz de ser ejecutado por el sistema operativo destino; ha de atenerse a las normas de dicho destino.

Los sistemas operativos modernos utilizan múltiples técnicas para optimizar el uso de la memoria. Y una de ellas es **la capacidad de compartir zonas de la misma** entre varias aplicaciones.

Para conseguir esto, la mayoría utiliza el concepto de *segmento* (no confundir con segmentos de memoria del procesador). Un *segmento* es un bloque de memoria con ciertos atributos.

Al compilar tu código, se generaría un ejecutable con varios de estos *segmentos*:

> [Código privado] (tu propio código)
>   [Código compartido] (librerías dinámicas: `printf`, `strcpy`)
>   [DatosDeSoloLectura] (los literales `"Bienvenida"` y `"Despedida"`).

El sistema operativo trata de forma distinta los distintos tipos de segmentos. Todos los mostrados aquí tienen una particularidad: **son de solo lectua**. Eso permite al sistema optimizar la memoria: si no se pueden escribir, compartir un segmento entre procesos es relativamente fácil: basta con *mapearlo* a las direcciones accesibles por cada uno.

Ahora ya podemos *entrever* lo que está pasando:

1. El compilador genera un ejecutable a partir de tu código. En el, en zonas marcadas como *de solo lectura*, se encuentran tus **literales** ( `"Bienvenida"` y `"Despedida"` ).
2. Creas una variable llamada `mensaje`, de tipo *puntero a `char`*, y haces que apunte **a la zona de memoria que contiene el literal `"Bienvenida"`**.
3. Intentas **modificar** la zona de memoria a la que apunta `mensaje`.
4. El Sistema Operativo te dice, *educadamente*, que estás intentando saltarte sus mecanismos de protección de memoria.

¿ Podemos evitar esto ? Bueno, hay varias formas. Quizás la mas sencilla sea esta:

```
int main( void ) {
   char mensaje[] = "Bienvenida";
   printf( "Direccion: %p\n", mensaje );

   strcpy( mensaje, "Despedida" );
   printf( "Direccion: %p\n", mensaje );

  return 0;
}
```

Como ves, la única diferencia es como se ha declarado `mensaje`. Algo sutil ... pero importante :-)

1. El compilador genera un ejecutable a partir de tu código. En el, en zonas marcadas como *de solo lectura*, se encuentran tus **literales** ( `"Bienvenida"` y `"Despedida"` ).
2. Solicitas al compilador una zona de memoria *automática* con capacidad suficiente para contener el literal `"Bienvenida"`. A esa zona accederemos mediante un puntero `mensaje`.
3. El compilador **copia** el literal `"Bienvenida"` desde su posición original a la zona de memoria apuntada por `mensaje`.
4. **Modificas** la zona de memoria a la que apunta `mensaje`.

Puesto que ahora estás utilizando un bloque de memoria declarado como *automático*, **está garantizado** que podrás escribir en él sin problemas (bueno, mas o menos ... pero lo dejamos ya).

**Nota** que toda la *parrafada* anterior es **dependiente del sistema operativo**. Dicho de otra manera: tu código fallará en Linux y el Windows. **Funcionará** perfectamente en, por ejemplo, MS-DOS.

**Nota2**: Por sugerencia en los comentarios, he arreglado un poco el código: corregir la definición de `main`, usar `"%p"` para imprimir punteros, y colocar el `return 0` final.

Comment: A tu respuesta le falta mencionar que `%d` es para enteros, si se quiere imprimir punteros es `%p` para ser perfecta.